# Deploying and hosting a PWA in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA on Ionic, and I have tested it locally on localhost: 8100 and I have also uploaded the production version to the Firebase hosting and It works.
But what I want to do is be able to host a PWA on a NodeJS server. It's possible?
I have not found clear information about it ...

Any ideas or docummentation about it?

Best regards.

Comment: Actually, it is not difficult. You just copy your **www** folder to **node.js file structure** and respond with **index.html**

Comment: Thanks @hyuck-kang, I did what you said, and I uploaded the generated www folder after executing the ionic build --prod command to a secure node.js server (HTTPS) and it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need have VPS, after then you install nodejs and PM2 run background nodejs, install nginx config proxy run nodejs, you can see:[How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04),[How To Set Up a Node.js Application for Production on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-centos-7)

```html
//install pm2
$ npm install pm2 -g
$ cd /var/www/app-nodejs
$ pm2 start app.js

//install nginx on CentOS 7
sudo yum install nginx -y

//if using ubuntu, you install nginx on Ubuntu
sudo apt-get install nginx -y

//config nginx on CentOS 7
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

//edit file nginx.conf
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    
//restart nginx on CentOS 7
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: Thanks @skipperhoam, your recommendations on VPS, pm2 and nginx will be very useful for me to deploy a node.js server in production mode.
My question was a mix, on the one hand I had the doubt of how to deploy a PWA on node.js and on the other leave the server in production mode. With the indications of Hyuck Kang and yours, I think the resolution of the matter is on track.